# Non-uniform coupon collector

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coupon-collector

I'm trying to figure out some simple bounds for the coupon collector problem with non-uniform coupon distribution in the best and worst case. I suspect the best case is uniform distribution with n log n coupons. What is it for worst case distribution?

Paper below looks relevant, but the setting is more general and I'm not sure how to get a simpler expression out of Theorem 3.1

http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v20i2p33/pdf

Comment: I do not think there is a worst case distribution. Given any distribution, you can make a distribution which is worse than that. This can be done, for example, by subtracting some small probability from the rarest coupon and adding it to the most abundant one.

Comment: My guess is that if the rarest coupon has a probability $r$ of occurring then the expected number of coupons required is bounded below by $\dfrac1r$ and above by $\dfrac{\gamma-\log_e(r)}{r} + \dfrac{1}{2}$.  Which end of this range you are at depends on how common the other coupons are.

Comment: I think this problem was first considered by von Schelling in 1934. (see Coupon Collecting for Unequal Probabilities,
Amer. Math. Monthly, 61, no. 5, 306–311). He gave an exact expression for the expected number of coupons needed to complete a set with a non-uniform coupon distribution. This expression is simple enough that you can easily get bounds for the best and worst cases. You can also check out my paper (http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v15i1n31/pdf), which has a result similar to von Schelling's.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer to allow the question to be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, there is no worst case. If coupon type $i$ has probability $p_i$ of being drawn, the expected time to draw all types is at least $\frac1{p_i}$, which grows without bound as $p_i\to0$.